# Replace SELECT INTO statement with a cursor ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is the query. How to replace `SELECT INTO` statement with a cursor?

I'm newbie in Oracle

Thanks for your help

```
SELECT CEQ_LISTE_TYPE_QUESTIONS.ID_LISTE_TYPE_QUESTION
        INTO vintIdListeTypeQuestion
        FROM CEQ_FORMULAIRES
        inner join CEQ_LISTE_TYPE_QUESTIONS
          on CEQ_LISTE_TYPE_QUESTIONS.ID_LISTE_TYPE_FORMULAIRE=CEQ_FORMULAIRES.ID_TYPE_FORMULAIRE 
             AND CEQ_LISTE_TYPE_QUESTIONS.WEBCODE='ITEM_BETA_LACTAMASE'
WHERE CEQ_FORMULAIRES.ID_FORMULAIRE=to_number(out_rec.ID_FORMULAIRE) 
and ceq_formulaires.date_inactive is null;
```

Comment: Usually people are looking to do the opposite. What is your requirement?

Comment: Because an error http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01422.php

Comment: That means you should write your query to return 1 row. AND DON'T USE where rownum <= 1, because that will return a random row!

Comment: Error:

ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
Cause:

You tried to execute a SELECT INTO statement and more than one row was returned.
Action:

The options to resolve this Oracle error are:
Rewrite your SELECT INTO statement so that only one row is returned.
Replace your SELECT INTO statement with a cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error tells you that the query returns more than 1 row, so you should determine which row you need. Here an example how to fetch the most recent row based on a date field I thought up in ceq_list_type_questions "some_date".

```
select max(q.id_liste_type_question) keep (dense_rank last order by q.some_date) into vintidlistetypequestion
from   ceq_formulaires f
join   ceq_liste_type_questions q on q.id_liste_type_formulaire = f.id_type_formulaire
where  f.id_formulaire = to_number(out_rec.id_formulaire) 
and    f.date_inactive is null
and    q.webcode = 'ITEM_BETA_LACTAMASE'
```

Comment: You're mixing a windowing function with the [`FIRST`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions065.htm#i1000901) modifier of an aggregate, this won't work. The windowing function (with `OVER`) will not aggregate and therefore would return the same number of rows as the original. The correct synthax of `FIRST` is `MAX(...) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY yyy)`

Comment: Thanks, Vincent. I edited my answer. I was too lazy to first create the tables in order to test my query. whoops.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want to process your multiple rows in a loop, it's as simple as

```
BEGIN
    FOR curs IN (SELECT     ceq_liste_type_questions.id_liste_type_question
                 FROM       ceq_formulaires
                 INNER JOIN ceq_liste_type_questions ON ceq_liste_type_questions.id_liste_type_formulaire=ceq_formulaires.id_type_formulaire 
                                                    AND ceq_liste_type_questions.webcode = 'ITEM_BETA_LACTAMASE'
                 WHERE      ceq_formulaires.id_formulaire = TO_NUMBER(out_rec.id_formulaire) 
                 AND        ceq_formulaires.date_inactive IS NULL)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(curs.id_liste_type_question);  -- do what you need to do
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

But, as BazzPsychoNut mentions, if it's a requirement that your SQL return/operate on a single row, you'll need to modify your query to meet that requirement.